# CSS text hiding behind DIV in some cases

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/hg25u/

I have made the HTML text on the right editable, so if you click inside the `Result` block (bottom right) you can actually change it by typing. Now if you place your typing cursor above the text:

`Bonorum has. His ut cibo quas tantas,`

and hit `Enter` on your keyboard, you will see that the text hides behind the grey DIV tag just below it, it shouldn't do that and I figured its a CSS problem but I cant get it to work. Its supposed to appear BELOW the grey DIV tag not hide behind it like its doing. If you mess around you will see it does that in a lot of instances when you hit Enter, sometimes it behaves properly sometimes it doesn't.

It should not hide text behind those grey DIV bars at any given moment. When you hit Enter it's supposed to continue the text line BELOW the grey DIV tag.

Any help would be appreciated

Also please have a look at this image to understand it better http://bayimg.com/eaIImAaef

Comment: this looks fine, could you perhaps include a screenshot, I can't seem to find anything wrong

Comment: No problem, heres an image screenshot link with info about my problem. [Image Link](http://bayimg.com/eaIImAaef) any assistance would be great

Answer (score 0):

The line-height needs to be the same size as the `.gate` and the `.fencepost` height needs to be however many lines of text you want in each block multiplied by the line-height.

```
body{ 
  font-size: 12px; 
  line-height: 20px; /* set base line-height */
}

.fencepost {
  float: left; 
  width: 1px; 
  height: 100px; /* 20px (line-height) multiplied by 5 lines of text */
}

.gate {
  float: left; 
  clear: left; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 20px; /* same as line-height */
  background-color: #eee; 
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.newsletterContent {
  width:600px;
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/cg6yC/

Comment: Doesnt quite work, have a look at [http://jsfiddle.net/Kv3Fm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Kv3Fm/1/)

Comment: Working as expected in Firefox, Safari and Chrome on OSX. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I tried it in both chrome and firefox on windows. It still become disordered after a few lines :(

Answer (score -1):

Look to see if you can use the z-index attribute to force the div behind the text.

Comment: Nope. z-index won't work because it will still appear in the same position just above the grey DIV this time. Its not supposed to be on the same line as that grey DIV at all. If you have a look at how its behaving for all the other lines of text when you hit `Enter`, that's how its supposed to behave for all of them.